# Exchange online/0365 permissions for viewing mail traces

Tags: email, exchange, azure, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I'm checking 0365 mail traces with the "Get-MessageTrace" command from the exchange online cmdlets.

What is the minimum permissions required to run the Get-MessageTrace command? Does the user have to be a global admin or is it possible to grant just the permission to check mail traces and no other admin privileges?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need Global Admin.

There are 3 default roles in Exchange that can review message traces

- Organization Management
- Compliance Management
- Help Desk

Global admin and the Exchange server admin O365 roles are assigned the Organization Management role by default.  The actual rights needed I"m not sure of.